# How to fill a button with an image in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to fill a `Button` with an `Image`. The button resides within a Grid. The problem is that the image is not fully filling the button. I have also tried to use the `ImageButton` control.

Here is how I am building my U.I:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="VotingGrid" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Image="yay.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
  <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Image="meh.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</Grid>
```

It currently looks like the image attached below, but I'd like to image to fill my button.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I tried the same It did not happen maybe becuase of the image resolution and button size. There is one way to do it, overlap the button over the image and set button opacity to 0. You can do the overlapping in gridlayout or absolute layout.

Comment: @AkashAmin I was looking for a "cleaner" approach.

Comment: Yes I searched for it but with got nothing, lets see if we can get some other answers. I'll be following this thread.Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try to place an image instead of button.

You can make use of **Tap Gesture Gesture Recognizer** to take click events.

Try something like this :

```
<Image Source="tapped.jpg">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"  />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

The code for the event handler

```
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    var imageSender = (Image)sender;
    // Do something
    DisplayAlert ("Alert", "Tap gesture recoganised", "OK");
}
```

---

Refer : [Adding a Tap Gesture Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/tap/#Using_Xaml)

Comment: Can you make it bindable with mvvm?

Comment: @batmaci According to the referenced link, you can use ICommand.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used it myself but maybe you can use this one from XLab

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageButton

Comment: I did but I still faced the same issue.

Comment: Then maybe you can go for the tappable image  , with a frame around it to give the feel of a button .

Comment: Thanks! In the end I went for a similar idea: a tappable frame with an image in the background.