# How to make the whole button image

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the ImageButton and would like that by taking the image by source it fills every button. The problem is that the image appears small simply on the right side. I want it to occupy every button

```
<ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
            <controls:ImageButton x:Name="CmdVoltar"  BackgroundColor="#1C97D5" TextColor="White" FontSize="Small"  WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,0,50,0"></controls:ImageButton>

        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>





CmdVoltar.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Agmovel.Img.btnVoltar.png");
```

Comment: It's appearing small and on the right side because you're setting the size and setting the `HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"`. Try removing the explicit size and using `Fill` for the Horizontal and Vertical options.

Comment: @amara- What is your `controls:ImageButton` what properties it have, until we know it would be difficult to answer, Or post total code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294834/how-to-fill-a-button-with-an-image-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using the default button with images, it has several issues.

You can use a package such as https://github.com/robinmanuelthiel/flexbutton